# How to write a stored procedure that returns a table with the difference between two timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am creating a stored procedure and I need to go through the result of a query comparing the first event with the second, if the first event is of type entry and the second event is of type exit subtract the second event with the first event and so with Each pair of events. The result of my query is something like the following table.

```
IdUsuario            eventos             tipo
1323-3123-13123 2016-12-02 20:55:00.000 Entrada
5656-5656-2323  2016-12-23 10:57:09.000 Salida
1111-2222-3333  2016-11-23 22:25:14.000 Entrada
3333-4444-5555  2016-12-19 22:23:39.000 Salida
```

My code:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateAssistanceReport1]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
         @date datetime     
        ,@cardholderguid uniqueidentifier
        ,@contarNull bit --si el valor es 1 devuelve los valores nulos.

    AS

    BEGIN
          SET NOCOUNT ON;
          --Declaracion de variables
          DECLARE @Counter INT
          DECLARE @FinalTable table (fecha date, entrada datetime, salida datetime, minutos smallint)
          DECLARE @torniqueteEntrada1 uniqueidentifier = '837F4409-DCAA-4D49-8FD4-170C31A85843';
          DECLARE @torniqueteEntrada2 uniqueidentifier = 'D5FDFEA0-DC88-4388-B9C3-E5D5B54A4C13';
          DECLARE @torniqueteSalida1 uniqueidentifier = '0544C492-E37F-4E0C-A3D8-546182B83DA3';
          DECLARE @torniqueteSalida2 uniqueidentifier = '6E13EE80-2818-4D18-BAAA-ED4AAA968A43';
          DECLARE @deviceGuid uniqueidentifier 

          DECLARE @puertaId uniqueidentifier;
          DECLARE @eventoRef datetime;
          DECLARE @eventoSgte datetime;
          DECLARE @pRef bit;
          DECLARE @pSgte bit;

          --DECLARE @horaModificada TIME
          --SET @Counter = 1

        --declaramos el cursor
        DECLARE CursorEventos cursor for
            SELECT DISTINCT LocalEventTimestamp, DeviceGuid       
               FROM Events.dbo.vw_Events
                 WHERE CardholderGuid = @cardholderguid
                  and (convert(date,[LocalEventTimestamp])= @date)
                  and (DeviceGuid = @torniqueteEntrada1 or DeviceGuid = @torniqueteEntrada2 or DeviceGuid =@torniqueteSalida1 or DeviceGuid = @torniqueteSalida2) 
            ORDER BY LocalEventTimestamp ASC

    open CursorEventos;


    fetch next from CursorEventos 
            into @eventoRef, @puertaId;
        --transformamos el valor de la puerta para facilitar la comprension 

        if (@puertaId in (@torniqueteSalida1, @torniqueteSalida2))
        begin
            --Salida
            set @pRef = 0;
        end;
        else if (@puertaId in (@torniqueteEntrada1, @torniqueteEntrada2))
        begin
            --Entrada
            set @pRef = 1;
        end;

    fetch next from CursorEventos 
            into @eventoRef, @puertaId;
        --transformamos el valor de la puerta para facilitar la comprension 

        if (@puertaId in (@torniqueteSalida1, @torniqueteSalida2))
        begin
            --Salida
            set @pRef = 0;
        end;
        else if (@puertaId in (@torniqueteEntrada1, @torniqueteEntrada2))
        begin
            --Entrada
            set @pRef = 1;
        end;    

            --caso que la primera tupla sea una salida y se desee contar
            if (@contarNull = 1)
            begin
              if (@pRef = 0)
              begin
                 insert into @FinalTable (fecha, entrada, salida,minutos) values(@date,@eventoRef,@eventoSgte,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@eventoRef,@eventoSgte))
              end;
            end;

            while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            begin
                if (@pSgte != @pRef)
                 begin
                 if (@pRef = 1)
                  begin
                    insert into @FinalTable (fecha, entrada,salida,minutos) values(@date, @eventoRef, @eventoSgte,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@eventoRef,@eventoSgte))
                  end;

              --registra el cambio en el acceso
              set @pRef = @pSgte;

              --avanzamos los cursores
              set @eventoRef = @eventoSgte;

                fetch next from CursorEventos 
            into @eventoRef, @puertaId;

            --transformamos el valor de la puerta para facilitar la comprension
            if (@puertaId in (@torniqueteSalida1, @torniqueteSalida2))
            begin
                --Salida
                set @pSgte = 0;
            end;
            else if (@puertaId in (@torniqueteEntrada1, @torniqueteEntrada2))   
            begin
                --Entrada
                set @pSgte = 1;
            end;
            end;


            end;
    close CursorEventos;
    deallocate CursorEventos;

    --caso que la ultima tupla sea una entrada y se desee contar
        if (@contarNull = 1)
        begin
            if (@pRef = 1)
            begin
                insert into @FinalTable (fecha, entrada,salida,minutos) values(@date, @eventoRef,null,0)
            end;
        end;

        if ((select COUNT(fecha) from @FinalTable) = 0)
        begin 
            insert into @FinalTable (fecha, entrada, salida, minutos)
            values(@date,null,null,0);
        end

        select @cardholderguid as chGuid, fecha, entrada, salida, minutos from @FinalTable
END
```

I want it to return the date I passed by parameter, input, output, and the difference in minutes and when I run it remains processing the query without response. Please if anyone can help me I will be grateful

Comment: Well firstly, in your `WHILE` loop you never fetch next from the cursor, so `FETCH_STATUS` will never not be 0 if it enters the loop....

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can probably do this in a single query without involving cursors at all, by doing something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT @Date fecha, E1.LocalEventTimestamp, E2.LocalEventTimestamp salida,
    DateDiff(MINUTE, E1.LocalEventTimestamp, E2.LocalEventTimestamp) minutos     
FROM Events.dbo.vw_Events E1
    JOIN Events.dbo.vw_Events E2 ON E1.CardholderGuid = E2.CardholderGuid
        AND E1.LocalEventTimestamp = E2.LocalEventTimestamp
        AND ((E1.DeviceGuid = @torniqueteEntrada1 AND E2.DeviceGuid = @torniqueteSalida1)
            OR (E1.DeviceGuid = @torniqueteEntrada2 AND E2.DeviceGuid = @torniqueteSalida2))
WHERE E1.CardholderGuid = @cardholderguid
    and (convert(date,[E1.LocalEventTimestamp])= @date)
ORDER BY E1.LocalEventTimestamp ASC
```

What's happening here is you're getting the first record you're interested in (E1) and the second record you're interested in (E2) which have the same date and cardholder Guid. The `join` statement ensures that the two records are for the same entry and exit device guid. Then it pulls in the difference in the timestamp with the other data you're interested in, and that should be that. Much more efficient than a cursor, and arguably quite a bit easier to read (hopefully).

Comment: So I could do it but they ask me to do it with a stored procedure as a requirement and also I have to add more conditions that I think that with a query I can not solve it

Comment: You can wrap the above query in a stored procedure if that is the requirement. Indeed the above query sort of expects it in order to populate the parameters for @date, etc. If the above query cannot be modified to support your extra conditions (and I would advise you to try, since the cursor approach will be horribly inefficient; could you perhaps use a table variable populated with the values for all of your other conditions and join that to the query?) then I have already explained why your original approach never completed.

Comment: The stored procedure executes it and remains processing infinitely apparently without returning anything

Comment: Anyway I will try to prove with your proposal

Comment: Stored procedure executes indefinitely because you need to add another one of these lines: `fetch next from CursorEventos 
        into @eventoRef, @puertaId;` after `set @pRef = @pSgte;` inside your `WHILE` loop. Otherwise it's just repeatedly checking whether it successfully read the first row, which of course it did. Incidentally, your stored procedure isn't going to return anything, it's just going to populate @FinalTable and then exit. It'll never show you the results. You need to run a select: `SELECT * FROM @FinalTable` to get a result from it.

Comment: Nothing I already did what you told me to fix as I have the code to modify it and when I process the stored procedure is processed the query infinitely

Comment: I think you've still got your `fetch` statement in the wrong place. Currently it looks like it's inside the `if @pSgte != @pRef` statement, which means that when the two values are equal, the `fetch` statement won't be executed and the variables won't be updated. At that point you'll stop looping through your cursor and `FETCH_STATUS` will be zero forever more.

Comment: Hi, I have a problem with the stored procedure. Thanks for your help and your time, the result of the stored procedure is a table, but I would like to have it returned to fill a table I created in a database. Please if you could help me I will be very grateful thanks in advance

Comment: Just turn the `SELECT` query into an `INSERT` query. `INSERT INTO your_table (fecha, entrada, salida, minutos) SELECT DISTINCT ... `, where "..." is the rest of the query I quoted in my answer.